# How to test real ads from admob

Tags: flutter, admob

I implemented Admob in a flutter application, test ads are displaying as expected, however, how can one test real ads without breaking Admob's rules, i made some ads restrictions and i want to see if they are really applied.

Comment: I think you can try build the release app, install it on your device and check if it applied

Answer (score 0):

Would not recommend the same. With real ads, unwanted clicks might occur, breaking the Admob guidelines. If the test ad is working, real ads will usually display, without issues.